# Undefined reference to Singleton::Singleton()

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to get the first basic singleton example from [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com.au/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8)
working, but this has me stumped.

This code compiles cleanly with `g++ -c Singleton.cpp`:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance();
protected:
    Singleton();
private:
    static Singleton* _instance;
};

Singleton* Singleton::_instance = 0;

Singleton* Singleton::Instance() {
    if (_instance == 0) {
        _instance = new Singleton;
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

But when I add a skeletal main() and compile with `g++ Singleton.cpp` I get `undefined reference to 'Singleton::Singleton()'`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You declared a constructor (you do not need), but left out he definition.

Comment: @DieterLücking _"you do not need"_ That's not entirely true. At least it should be made `private`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sure - damn anti pattern

Comment: @DieterLücking I knew it was something stupidly basic.  Cheers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Although it is probably a dupe, it's also the literal textbook example.  I'm guessing a few folks might have the same problem.

Comment: @Daniel Well, I could give your question an upvote so future researchers may benefit from finding it. On the other hand it's a very trivial mistake you made that's clearly covered in the marked duplicate and seems to be an outcome of low research efforts. I think I'll just leave everything as is. Be happy having your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never added a definition for

```
Singleton();
```

Which is used in `Singleton* Singleton::Instance()` by

```
_instance = new Singleton;
```

Typically you should and can layout a singleton like:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance() { static Singleton s; return &s; }
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
private:
    Singleton() = default;
};
```

Comment: Great answer, I'll definitely be using that snippet.  But it strays a bit far from the textbook example, maybe you could add a bit about using a default constructor?

Comment: @Daniel `Singleton() = default;` is basically just a C++11 way to write `Singleton(){}`.  If forces the compile to generate `Singleton(){}`;

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! What does `= delete` mean then? Is it a syntax sugar of what?

Comment: @Tim It tells the compile that the function does not exits and using it will generate a nice compiler error saying you are trying to use a deleted function.  In the days before C++11 you would have to declare it as private and not implement it and the error message about using it wasn't as nice

Comment: Thanks. Is `_instance = new Singleton;` the same as `_instance = new Singleton();`? Which one is preferred?

Comment: @Tim In this case they are the same.  Which is preferred is really a matter of style.